# Asking the user permission to use camera in advance of using the camera

Tags: ios, ipad

In IOS 8 users are now asked permission to use the device camera. This is fine but my problem is I want to ask permission well before the user actually needs the camera (when the user first loads the app) I know this can be done when asking the user permission to access camera roll in advance.

Comment: There's no API for that. If you have a good use case I suggest filing an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: I don't know your particular use-case for this, but Apple's design guidelines state that out of context pop-ups can be jarring and they recommend against it. I read that specifically about prompting for an apple ID to restore in-app purchases on launch, and while this isn't nearly as bad it might be worth considering this recommendation.

Comment: @matt The `AVCaptureDevice` has a class method `requestAccessForMediaType` that does this.

Answer (score 3):

The App only asks for permission is when the camera is actually accessed, so you have to access it. You can of course do this in the background with AVCaptureSession and don't show the images you get.
Here is a simple [example](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/715xx4loqo5can9/715/715_user_privacy_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf) on how to use AVCaptureSession for this purpose. 
I wouldn't be using this, as the user doesn't know what the camera is used for - except in obvious examples (camera app). The user may get the confused, why the camera is turned on. Either you can make a view describing what you use the camera for and then activate the camera in the background to prompt the user, or leave it as it is, as it doesn't take much time.

Comment: @Aalbert - I tried the example code but it didn't work - Nevertheless, your answer gave me the idea of creating an imagePicker in my initial viewController and then setting [imagePicker.view setHidden:YES]; This prompts the user camera alert without the user using the camera. It works but a bit messy !!

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question to help others with a similar problem, I'm using the following code - works great because is asks the user for permission to use the device camera before an imagePicker has even been created.

```
   AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:NULL];
if (deviceInput)
{
    // user has excepted camera


} else {

    // user has NOT excepted camera


}
```

Comment: This is not correct. Use `AVCatpureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:completionHandler:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated answer (Swift 5):

```
private func openCamera() {
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
    case .authorized: // the user has already authorized to access the camera.
        self.setupCaptureSession()

    case .notDetermined: // the user has not yet asked for camera access.
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (granted) in
            if granted { // if user has granted to access the camera.
                print("the user has granted to access the camera")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.setupCaptureSession()
                }
            } else {
                print("the user has not granted to access the camera")
                self.handleDismiss()
            }
        }

    case .denied:
        print("the user has denied previously to access the camera.")
        self.handleDismiss()

    case .restricted:
        print("the user can't give camera access due to some restriction.")
        self.handleDismiss()

    default:
        print("something has wrong due to we can't access the camera.")
        self.handleDismiss()
    }
}
```